# bdutil keeps adding many sshkeys to project metadata

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a process that launches a micro instance with a startup script.  The startup script installs bdutil and launches a spark cluster.  The problem I'm running into is that during the deploy of the cluster, several ssh keys for root user seem to get added to the project metadata area.  They do not get removed afterward.  Over time, enough keys are added that the maximum bytes limit for metadata are exceeded and no VMs can be created.

Can I tell bdutil to not push ssh keys to project metadata, or can I clean them up after the cluster shuts down?

Thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I decided to manually install a keypair on the bootstrap server, so when it gets pushed to project metadata it is always the same public key and I will avoid pushing new keys with each bootstrap instance.